# can not extend a generic class in symfony using phpunit

Tags: symfony, phpunit

I have a first class :

```
namespace Tests\AppBundle\EntitiesConstraints;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validation;

class EntityTest extends WebTestCase
{
...}
```

and a second one :

```
namespace Tests\AppBundle\EntitiesConstraints;

use AppBundle\Entity\AnnonceSuperClasse;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validation;
use Tests\AppBundle\EntitiesConstraints\EntityTest;

class AnnoncesAssertTest extends EntityTest
{
...}
```

The problem is that apparently, i can not extend EntityTest.

I got this message :

> Fatal error: Class 'Tests\AppBundle\EntitiesConstraints\EntityTest'
>   not found in
>   C:\wamp\www\projets\Tabadoul\tests\EntitiesConstraints\AnnoncesAssertTest.php
>   on line 9

Thanks in advance for the help !

Comment: Probably you haven't configured the autoloader to look for classes in the tests folder

Comment: How would you do that in symfony 3.4 please ?

Comment: Paste composer.json, especially autoload-dev part

Comment: https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload-dev

Comment: @kuba_ceg past it where please ?

Comment: In Your question